# Dialogflow SDK or Dialogflow REST API, which is faster in term of response time?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have used Dialogflow for developing the app for Google Assistant. I have created intents and entities in the Dialogflow web GUI and I'm using a webhook response for further conversation.

Now I want to build a chatbot that is part of an existing Android or iOS app and use the code I already wrote for Dialogflow as part of this. What do I need to be aware of when I do so? It looks like I can use the SDK for that platform or make calls to the Dialogflow REST API. Which is faster or are there any tradeoffs? Can I use the Dialogflow NLP without going over the network?

Comment: When you say the "SDK", which one are you talking about? (Your question is a bit vague - examples and links would help clarify what you're asking and why.)

Comment: Okay, Let take an example in which you have to integrate chatbot in your existing android/ios app.  So at that moment of time, when user ask your app some query, should you be call the rest api for parsing natural text or use the SDK method ( in the app's package) ? Which one of the approach would provide you the fast response? Is there any method in which we can use dialogflow natural language parsing power without calling REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to be aware of when moving from fulfillment that was built for Actions on Google to using this to also provide responses for other platforms. Actions on Google expects the responses to be formatted slightly differently, and if you're using AoG specific characteristics (such as a SimpleResponse object or a Card object), then it might not appear for other Dialogflow integrations. So you'll need to go over your webhook code to make sure what you send back works across platforms. Your logic and the Dialogflow UI builder should pretty much remain the same - it is just your backend that might need some work.

To make the call, as you say, you can either do the REST call yourself or use the SDK built by Dialogflow. While the SDK will be slightly faster, since it is using ProtoBuffs instead of REST, the difference will likely be fairly slight in most cases. If you're planning to stream audio, you will likely need to either use the SDK or your own ProtoBuff implementation because REST doesn't handle that as well. If you're just sending text, and are more comfortable with doing REST APIs, then this is a perfectly reasonable approach.

There is no "local Dialogflow" library. All calls have to go over the network. There are other libraries that do Speech-to-Text and NLP locally if that is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Dialogflow API V1 is deprecated and will be shut down on October 23th, 2019.
That means that the official Javascript, native Android, native iOS and Cordova clients will stop working since they all use V1. There's no word if and when these clients will be upgraded to V2. 
So the best bet right now is to use the REST APIs.